# Uploading an image and parameters in one one API call

Tags: node.js, swift, mongodb, alamofire

i'm having some problems creating an object + uploading an image at the same API call. the server was created by be (Node.js + mongoDB). its a POST that used multer to extract all data (form - data) and all tests  using postman seems to be working fine.

i'm using Alamofire in my IOS app

[post with content type](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/nevgauker/9c9ffd2a77c5d0d16a3ebdd6e37a9810.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

[upload and multi form data](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/nevgauker/3fd50b1d01cd238c179bde4729e6c499.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

[my server code](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/nevgauker/196647ad135069ea64417c1d65141d27.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Comment: What have you tried? Add some code.

Comment: add this code to question please. And describe it more

Comment: basically i'm failing sending a request to my server that contain some parameter and an image data ( creating a new object , uploading an image  and saving the url in that object). i tested my server using  postman post request and form-data an it seems to works just fine .tried to do the same from my app and nothing works. technologies and code snippets are all in the original post